# Плиточный дизайн

Tags: html, css

При верстке psd наткнулся на плиточный дизайн. Мне нужно понять что использовать: flexbox, grid, div или таблицы использовать фреймворки нельзя только чистый css. В какую сторону копать и если можно привести пример. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Лучше используй **Bootstrap Grid**:она полностью реализует все твои потребности, если использовать фиксированный маргинг ([вот пример](http://bitjournal.media/))
Прочитать подробнее про **Bootstrap** можно [тут](http://mybootstrap.ru/).
Прочитать подробнее про **Bootstrap Grid** можно [тут](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).

Comment: Спасибо конечно но можно без бутстрапа?

Comment: Да, можно, но чем Вас не устраивает bootstrap?Ведь, с плиточным дизайном будут проблемы с адаптацией

Comment: @nrjshka это не bootstrap, потому что ряды разной высоты.

Comment: @KAGGDesign в чем проблема в структуризации блоков?

Comment: @nrjshka а вы попробуйте вывести через bootstrap вот то, что нарисовано: https://monosnap.com/file/mICXQtrB9soQDaHPxn4XmnQv4a5a8A

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой плагин - [isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/). С его помощью можно получить очень похожую верстку в режиме [masonry](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html).